# My GupShup Bot got lost?

Tags: bots, gupshup

I've created a bot for Facebook Messenger from GupShup but when I try to access it from the site it does not appear in the Dashboard - > My Bots, but it still works on Facebook, so basically I've got a bot I can't modify, anyone got the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a login issue, Firefox 60.0 (64bit) has some issue, works fine in incognito mode or chrome